# Need Help in following MS Access 2010 VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

i am using this code and its not showing any error but not storing entered data into table.

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strItem As String

strSQL = "SELECT hotel_ID, Hotel_Name FROM hotels"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

rs.AddNew
   ' rs.Fields("Hotel_ID") = frmHotel_ID          Hotel_ID is a autonumber field
    rs.Fields("Hotel_Name") = frmHotel_Name
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps missing a call to .Update?

Comment: Good and Thanks, yeah i have missed it and now its working.... What a mistake i did

Comment: Great! Pleas mark the question as closed. Earning a rep ;-)

Comment: i am new here how do i mark as close please

Comment: Mark my answer as "accepted" by checking the \/ symbol

Comment: Check this out [About Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about)